Koha Elasticsearch Rebuild Error "Use of uninitialized value in string eq at /usr/share/koha/bin/search_tools/rebuild_elasticsearch.pl line 359"
I would really appreciate your help and support for this and many thanks in advance.
For quite some time I have been trying to configure elastic search in my Koha installation. The installation goes normally well. After restoring my own DB, the schema upgrade goes without errors, Biblios get indexed, but it fails to index Authorities and shows this error:
[Use of uninitialized value in string eq at /usr/share/koha/bin/search_tools/rebuild_elasticsearch.pl line 359.]

After Elastic installation and before rebuild status shows “green” with [curl http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty] but after rebuild status goes to “yellow”.
After install and rebuild the search works but the Elastic status shows “not running” in about page, while zebra also shows running (I think it still uses Zebra).
Yes, I did change the Search Engine to Elastic in administration. Rebuilding with zebra indexing also works fine.
I tried with multiple Ubuntu versions 18, 20, 22, 24, with Debian, with elastic 6, 7 and 8, but still the same error and “Elastic status not running”.
Some logs for trouble shooting FYKI:
Elasticsearch log shows this:
"at org.elasticsearch.persistent.NodePersistentTasksExecutor$1.doRun(NodePersistentTasksExecutor.java:34) ~[elasticsearch-8.15.0.jar:?] at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:984) ~[elasticsearch-8.15.0.jar:?] at org. elasticsearch. common. util. concurrent. AbstractRunnable. run(AbstractRunnable.java:26) ~[elasticsearch-8.15.0.jar:?] at java. util. concurrent. ThreadPoolExecutor. runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[?:?] at java. util. concurrent. ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker. run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[?:?] at java. lang. Thread. run(Thread.java:1570) ~[?:?] [2024-09-05T17:09:34,789][INFO ][o.e.i.g. DatabaseNodeService] [koha] successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-Country.mmdb] [2024-09-05T17:09:34,836][INFO ][o.e.i.g. DatabaseNodeService] [koha] successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-ASN. mmdb] [2024-09-05T17:09:35,532][INFO ][o.e.i.g. DatabaseNodeService] [koha] successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-City.mmdb] [2024-09-05T17:09:35,825][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a. AllocationService] [koha] current. health=”YELLOW” message=”Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[.ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2024.09.05-000001][0], [.ds-ilm-history-5-2024.09.05-000001][0]]]).” Previous.health=”RED” reason=”shards started [[.ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2024.09.05-000001][0], [.ds-ilm-history-5-2024.09.05-000001][0]]”
koha log shows this:
==> /var/log/koha/library/api-error.log <== ==> /var/log/koha/library/indexer-error.log <== 20240905 17:04:43 library-koha-indexer: client (pid 14599) killed by signal 15, stopping ==> /var/log/koha/library/indexer-output.log <== DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Table 'koha_library. zebraqueue' doesn't exist at /usr/share/koha/lib/Koha/Database.pm line 152. DBD::mysql::st fetchrow_arrayref failed: fetch() without execute() at /usr/share/koha/lib/Koha/Database.pm line 152. DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Table 'koha_library. zebraqueue' doesn't exist at /usr/share/koha/lib/Koha/Database.pm line 152. DBD::mysql::st fetchrow_arrayref failed: fetch() without execute() at /usr/share/koha/lib/Koha/Database.pm line 152. DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Table 'koha_library. zebraqueue' doesn't exist at /usr/share/koha/lib/Koha/Database.pm line 152. DBD::mysql::st fetchrow_arrayref failed: fetch() without execute() at /usr/share/koha/lib/Koha/Database.pm line 152. DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Table 'koha_library. zebraqueue' doesn't exist at /usr/share/koha/lib/Koha/Database.pm line 152. DBD::mysql::st fetchrow_arrayref failed: fetch() without execute() at /usr/share/koha/lib/Koha/Database.pm line 152. DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Table 'koha_library. zebraqueue' doesn't exist at /usr/share/koha/lib/Koha/Database.pm line 152. DBD::mysql::st fetchrow_arrayref failed: fetch() without execute() at /usr/share/koha/lib/Koha/Database.pm line 152. ==> /var/log/koha/library/intranet-error.log <== [Fri Aug 16 10:04:52.198945 2024] [cgi:error] [pid 14705] [client 192.168.1.106:55647] AH01215: concatenation (.) operator, even though there is no . in: /usr/share/koha/intranet/cgi-bin/installer/install.pl, referer: 192.168.1.110: 8080/cgi-bin/koha/installer/install.pl [Fri Aug 16 10:04:52.198950 2024] [cgi:error] [pid 14705] [client 192.168.1.106:55647] AH01215: your program.: /usr/share/koha/intranet/cgi-bin/installer/install.pl, referer:  192.168.1.110: 8080/cgi-bin/koha/installer/install.pl [Fri Aug 16 10:04:52.198952 2024] [cgi:error] [pid 14705] [client 192.168.1.106:55647] AH01215: : /usr/share/koha/intranet/cgi-bin/installer/install.pl, referer: 192.168.1.110: 8080/cgi-bin/koha/installer/install.pl [Fri Aug 16 10:04:56.582898 2024] [cgi:error] [pid 14705] [client 192.168.1.106:55647] AH01215: No locale installed. Localization cannot work and is therefore disabled at /usr/share/koha/lib/Koha/I18N.pm line 87.: /usr/share/koha/intranet/cgi-bin/installer/install.pl, referer: 192.168.1.110: 8080/cgi-bin/koha/installer/install.pl [Fri Aug 16 10:05:15.791760 2024] [cgi:error] [pid 14705] [client 192.168.1.106:55647] AH01215: No locale installed. Localization cannot work and is therefore disabled at /usr/share/koha/lib/Koha/I18N.pm line 87.: /usr/share/koha/intranet/cgi-bin/installer/install.pl, referer: 192.168.1.110: 8080/cgi-bin/koha/installer/install.pl [Fri Aug 16 10:05:20.097168 2024] [cgi:error] [pid 14705] [client 192.168.1.106:55647] AH01215: INSERT Version at /usr/share/koha/lib/C4/Installer.pm line 471.: /usr/share/koha/intranet/cgi-bin/installer/install.pl, referer:  192.168.1.110: 8080/cgi-bin/koha/installer/install.pl [Thu Sep 05 17:04:43.634269 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 68391] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 192.168.1.100:59117] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server httpd-UDS:0, referer: 192.168.1.110: 8080/cgi-bin/koha/admin/preferences.pl?tab=&op=search&searchfield=search+engine [Thu Sep 05 17:04:43.635447 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 68391] [client 192.168.1.100:59117] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /cgi-bin/koha/about.pl, referer: 192.168.1.110: 8080/cgi-bin/koha/admin/preferences.pl?tab=&op=search&searchfield=search+engine [Thu Sep 05 17:04:43.697293 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 68391] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: http: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /var/run/koha/library/plack.sock (localhost) failed [Thu Sep 05 17:04:43.697320 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 68391] [client 192.168.1.100:59117] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS, referer: 192.168.1.110: 8080/cgi-bin/koha/about.pl ==> /var/log/koha/library/opac-error.log <== ==> /var/log/koha/library/plack-api-error.log <== ==> /var/log/koha/library/plack-error.log <== Setting uid to "1001" 2024/09/05-17:04:37 Received QUIT. Running a graceful shutdown Sending children hup signal 2024/09/05-17:04:43 Worker processes cleaned up 2024/09/05-17:04:43 Server closing! Process Backgrounded 2024/09/05-17:04:45 Starman::Server (type Net::Server::PreFork) starting! pid(68631) Binding to UNIX socket file "/var/run/koha/library/plack.sock" Setting gid to "1001 1001" Setting uid to "1001"
